# Current Date till Hour in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sysdate

I want to get the date with just the current hour.

Using `trunc(sysdate)` gives us something like `2017-06-16 00:00:00`

But, I want the current hour as well :

```
2017-06-16 10:00:00
2017-06-16 11:00:00
```

and so on.

I want it to be a date (and not char), as I need it for comparison with a date column.

```
date_column <= day_with_hour
```

Answer (score 7):

[The `trunc()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions236.htm) takes a second optional argument, which default to `'DD'` to truncate the time to midnight. You can use `'HH'` instead (or `'HH24'` if you prefer for consistency with other formatting you're using elsewhere - it doesn't affect the result) to get what you want:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

select sysdate, trunc(sysdate, 'HH') from dual;

SYSDATE             TRUNC(SYSDATE,'HH')
------------------- -------------------
2017-06-16 09:27:43 2017-06-16 09:00:00
```

The date format models [are also in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA), and a subset of those are [allowed for `trunc()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions271.htm).

So your query would use:

```
date_column <= trunc(sysdate, 'HH')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alex. Exactly what I've been looking for.